# Why does '_.negate' uses apply with 'this' parameter in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm studying underscore.js and javascript programming.
While I'm seeing the source of underscore, I can't understand some part of it.

I can't understand why it uses apply with 'this' in the _.negate, because the other parts receive 'context's and use them.
Below is the source code.

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js

```
_.negate = function(predicate) {
    return function() {
        return !predicate.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

The places where _.negate is used are in _.reject and _.omit.
Seeing code of _.reject, it receives 'context' and use it for the context.

```
_.filter = _.select = function(obj, predicate, context) {
    var results = [];
    if (obj == null) return results;
    if (nativeFilter && obj.filter === nativeFilter) {
        return obj.filter(predicate, context);
    }
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (predicate.call(context, value, index, list)) results.push(value);
    });
    return results;
};



_.reject = function(obj, predicate, context) {
    return _.filter(obj, _.negate(predicate), context);
};
```

Please give me some explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in `_.reject` the filter function receives context as a third parameter negate only receives predicate

Answer (score 4):

The [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) call is doing two things at once:

1. It is setting the `this` that will be in effect inside `predicate`.
2. It is passing the anonymous function's argument list straight into `predicate` without having to care how many arguments are being used.

**(2)** should be clear enough if you know about [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) in JavaScript; `arguments` is an Array-like object which holds the function's current argument list, all functions in JavaScript are variadic (despite what their definition says) and `arguments` is how you work with the arguments when you don't know how many there are.

**(1)** should be clear with a quick look at how the `_.negate` return value is used. Inside `_.filter`, the `predicate` is invoked using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
predicate.call(context, value, index, list)
```

That sets `this` to `context` inside `predicate`. If `predicate` is actually `_.negate(original_predicate)` then that's effectively this:

```
var f = function() {
    return !original_predicate.apply(this, arguments);
};
f.call(context, ...)
```

so `original_predicate` will get called like `original_predicate.apply(context, arguments)` and the specified `this` (i.e. `context`) will get be in effect when `original_predicate` executes.

If `_.negate` just did this:

```
return function(a, b, c) {
    return !predicate(a, b, c);
};
```

then two bad things would happen:

1. The specified `context` would be lost.
2. Only three arguments would get through. This would be sufficient for `_.filter` but maybe not for other uses of `_.negate`.

Losing track of `context` would break a lot of code, using `Function.prototype.apply` to specify the `this` just happens to solve the argument list problem for free.